# How to change the language of the email dynamically according to user's language in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, email, locale, translate

I'm looking for a way to send a simple WordPress email according to user's language using `wp_mail()` function via a custom-built plugin. I'm able translate the email and receive the email in the right language once I switch WordPress language via Settings. But how to change the language of the email dynamically according to user's language?

I have saved a list of users with their preferred languages. The subject and email content is translated into different languages. For testing purposes, I have been trying to force the locale, but it does not seem to be doing anything and the email is still arriving in the default WordPress en_US locale.

```
$locale = 'es_ES';
switch_to_locale($locale);
$to      = 'test@email.com';
$subject = __('Email subject', 'textdomain');
$message = __('My email content', 'textdomain');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
restore_previous_locale();
```

I would be very grateful to receive some feedback, experience or knowledge how to briefly switch the locale for some strings and then restore it back to the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I finally got this to work.

1. First - make sure you do have .mo translation files ready with the appropriate translations
2. After calling `switch_to_locale($locale);` you have to also load textdomain. I used `load_plugin_textdomain()` function.

Here is the updated code if anyone comes across this threads:

```
$locale = 'es_ES';
switch_to_locale($locale);
load_plugin_textdomain('textdomain', false, basename( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) ) . '/languages');
$to      = 'test@email.com';
$subject = __('Email subject', 'textdomain');
$message = __('My email content', 'textdomain');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
restore_previous_locale();
```